# SonataAdmin: replace ID in breadcrumbs

Tags: symfony, breadcrumbs, sonata-admin

How can I replace Object's ID in SonataAdmin breadcrumbs by some other text?

If I set **__toString()** in my document, it works only for editing. When I attempt to create new record, there is something like `MyDocument:0000000000e09f5c000000006a48ef49` in the last breadcumb.

I'm searching for a method which allows me to set some text as the last breadcump if **Document::toString()** returns null.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This behaviour is implemented directly in the entity:

```
public function __toString()
{
    return $this->getFoo() ? : '-';
}
```

Bundles are using variants of this, including `return (string)$this->getFoo();` or `$this->getFoo() ? : 'n/a';` etc.

Related question: [toString method for SonataAdminBundle Listing in Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17545489/tostring-method-for-sonataadminbundle-listing-in-symfony2)

Comment: Thank you for the response! I mentioned this solution in my question. But what if I need to put some text depending on current locale,  
i.e. use a translator?

Comment: You mean if your `__toString()` returns empty value? Try returning `"empty_value"` and translate it in `messages.en.yml` file. If it does not help, it seems that breadcrumbs are printed here: https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/blob/2e9d4406a6cddc278a43c2c8f6297c33fbc6fb81/Resources/views/standard_layout.html.twig#L190 . You could override it with `|trans()` filter.

Comment: Thank you! I'll keep searching

Comment: Note this will work on the same instance as the entity being edited. Eg. if your __toString() method returns a name property, and the name is invalid in the form, the invalid name will also be displayed in the breadcrumb. Didn't find a fix for that though...

Answer (score 1):

BTW something cool to know, you can completely customize the breadcrumb via a Twig template:

```
{% block sonata_breadcrumb %}

    {% set _breadcrumb %}
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Library</a></li>
        <li class="active">Data</li>
    {% endset %}

    {{ parent() }}

{% endblock %}
```