# sonata admin label on breadcrumb

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, breadcrumbs

I have a little problem with sonata admin on Symfony.
I would like to change the default admin label in the breadcrumb:

[image]

but I can't find any solution. Can someone help me?

I found this function, but it doesn't work. It looks like that this function is not called.

```
public function buildBreadcrumbs($action, MenuItemInterface $menu = null) {
    $breadCrumb =  parent::buildBreadcrumbs($action, $menu);

    return $breadCrumb;
}
```

I use **Symfony 2.8**.

Comment: If you just want to modify the translations of labels, not their structure, you can override the `sonata_breadcrumb` block within the `SonataAdminBundle::standard_layout.html.twig` template. Put the correct translation domain for the `label` var, and translate your labels in it.

Comment: mmm i'm a newbie of sonata, do you have an example?

Comment: ps. i don't want translate the "List" but "Test Product" 
the correct breacrumb is
Dashboard / Product  / Product List
OR
Dashboard / Product List / Product List

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try to override `classNameLabel` property in your admin class:

```
// in your ProductAdmin class
public function configure()
{
    $this->classnameLabel = "Products";
}
```

Comment: You don't need to have this in the configure method, just add the protected var to the top of your ProductAdmin class: `protected $classnameLabel = 'Products';`

Comment: @AndreaG.Pigliafreddo You should mark this answer if it is correct for you.

Comment: @lopsided Thanks! It's much shorter and nicer. I think it results in cleaner code. You should have made it as an answer. Nevertheless thanks to Ekonoval for the valuable information.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to achieve what you want is to change translations messages.

If you really want to change the labels you can implement your own label generation strategy.

```
namespace Blast\CoreBundle\Translator;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Translator\LabelTranslatorStrategyInterface;

/**
 * Class LibrinfoLabelTranslatorStrategy.
 *
 * Provides a specific label translation strategy for Librinfo.
 * It is based on UnderscoreLabelTranslatorStrategy, but without the context,
 * and labels are prefixed by "librinfo.label."
 *
 * i.e. isValid => librinfo.label.is_valid
 */
class LibrinfoLabelTranslatorStrategy implements LabelTranslatorStrategyInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getLabel($label, $context = '', $type = '')
    {
        $label = str_replace('.', '_', $label);

        return sprintf('%s.%s.%s', "librinfo", $type, strtolower(preg_replace('~(?<=\\w)([A-Z])~', '_$1', $label)));
    }
}
```

define it as a service

```
blast_core.label.strategy.librinfo:
        class: Blast\CoreBundle\Translator\LibrinfoLabelTranslatorStrategy
```

then pass it to the definition of your admin service like so:

```
crm.organism:
        class: Librinfo\CRMBundle\Admin\OrganismAdmin
        arguments: [~, Librinfo\CRMBundle\Entity\Organism, LibrinfoCRMBundle:OrganismAdmin]
        tags:
            -   name: sonata.admin
                manager_type: orm
                group: Customers Relationship Management
                label_translator_strategy: blast_core.label.strategy.librinfo
```

You will have full control of your admin labels

Also see: [SonataAdmin: replace ID in breadcrumbs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19320465/sonataadmin-replace-id-in-breadcrumbs)