# SonataAdmin ID in breadcrumbs won't go away

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I know this question has been asked severally [SonataAdmin: replace ID in breadcrumbs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19320465/sonataadmin-replace-id-in-breadcrumbs) and [toString method for SonataAdminBundle Listing in Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17545489/tostring-method-for-sonataadminbundle-listing-in-symfony2) but none of the solutions offered worked for me.

Here's what i tried having in my entity

```
public function __toString()
{
    return $this->getFoo() ? : '-';
}

public function __toString()
{
    return ($this->getFoo()) ? : '';
}

public function __toString()
{
    return (string)$this->getFoo();
}

public function __toString()
{
    $this->getFoo() ? : 'n/a';
}
```

I still get IDs in both editing and create views. Anything else I might have forgotten? Using symfony 2.4 and latest version of Sonata Admin Bundle

Comment: Can you post your admin class code so we can take a look for possible mistakes?

Comment: sorry for delay, here is my [admin class](http://pastebin.com/6iLzUY48)

Comment: I also need your entity code to take a look at :)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/F6bxZ74L

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your entity class to this:

```
<?php

namespace ACME\MyBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Pipeline
 */
class Pipeline
{
    .... code goes here ....
    ....
    public function __toString()
    {
        return (string) $this->getTitle() ? $this->getTitle() : 'New';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much even though i delayed in response, was enganged in another project.